# Excel crashing when a value is set for a range

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to set a value in Excel VBA based on a condition, but it crashes each time with an error relating to stack space, and when I tried setting ForceFullCalculation on the workbook as advised in another SO post, the error I get is:

```
Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':

Method 'Value' of object 'Range' failed
```

The line of code in question

```
If Range("G4") = "Yes" Then

    Range("K4:L6").Interior.ColorIndex = 4 ' green
    Range("K4").Value = "x"

End If
```

There are multiple of these blocks in the code. 
When I comment out the line that sets the value 'x' the code seems to run fine.

```
If Range("G4") = "Yes" Then

    Range("K4:L6").Interior.ColorIndex = 4 ' green
    'Range("K4").Value = "x"

End If
```

Why would it crash when setting a single cell to the value 'x' after coloring the cells to green (or any color)?
The version used is Excel 2010 32-bit, on a machine with 8GB RAM.

Comment: Are you doing this inside an event like `Worksheet_Change`? Typically a stack space error is caused by recursion.

Comment: Yes, it's inside a WorkSheet_Change. Could you recommend doing it a different way to stop it crashing? I'm not sure where the recursion you mention is taking place, I'm a bit new to Excel VBA.

Comment: Then you need to add `Application.Enableevents = False` before changing cells (which will trigger your event again, and again etc) and then reset to True afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically a stack space error is caused by recursion, such as when you are changing cells from within a `Worksheet_Change` event, which then calls itself, changes the cells again, which calls the event again and so on. To avoid this, you can disable events before making the changes by adding:

```
Application.Enableevents = False ' disable event processing

' your code that makes the changes here

Application.Enableevents = True ' reset events again
```

Comment: Is there a simple way to tell which Excel VBA functions are recursive? That would really help avoiding or at least identifying similar problems occurring for anyone reading this in future.

Comment: Only logic. None of them are inherently recursive but logically if you *change* a cell from a `Change` event, or *select* a cell in a `SelectionChange` event, you will trigger that event again.